# 2 monitors with dual view on GeForce 6150 LE

Tags: windows-xp, vga, multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce, splitter

I have an HP Pavilion Media Center a1630n. 3.5 RAM, Athlon 64 X2 (W) 4600+ 2.4 GHz, Win xp 32bit media center edition.  The video card that came with it was Nvidia GeForce 6150 LE.  I put an Nvidia Geforce 8800GTS 640mb Gddr3 in it.  When I bought it way back when I used it for gaming and such.  Now the computer is just used for work.  I have 2 monitors hooked up to it for dual view.  It has two DVI inputs so each monitor was hooked up to each input. The Geforce 8800GTS just died on me.  So it is now using the original GeForce 6150 LE, and using just 1 monitor in the original vga input.

[image: vga splitter]

I want to still use two monitors on it using dual view.  Can I just buy a vga splitter (pictured above) and hook two monitors to it while using that original GeForce 6150 LE? Or will that be too much for it?  Would I be better off buying another Geforce 8800GTS 640mb (or similar).

Keep in mind that I only use it for web development/design work.  Not gaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a friend with a dell c521 that has the 6150LE. That card is just awful even for an integrated card. I would suggest just picking up a 8400gs on amazon or tiger you can usually find them for like $30 or less and they perfect for what you want to do. Plus you may be restricted to just cloning with a VGA splitter as it may not have the ability to see the second monitor (I read online that it may not work at all). If that is a path you really want to take I can test it out tomorrow (Thursday) with his and let you know.

Comment: I was just reading that you can only use clone and not dual view, so you don't have to test it out, but thank you:).  Something like this good? http://www.amazon.com/EVGA-512-P2-N738-LR-GeForce-PCI-Express-Graphics/dp/B0011FKI3M or http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B001GENPBK/ref=pd_lpo_k2_dp_sr_2?pf_rd_p=486539851&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe-1&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=B0011FKI3M&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=17P0HH8CS9946E1SH3M1

Comment: Yep that's it. Although that one is a little over priced here's the one we use at my company we have 50+ of these running with now problems:   http://www.amazon.com/nVidia-GeForce-Low-Profile-PCI-Express-ZT-84MEH4M-HSL/dp/B0037W6BP6/ref=sr_1_2?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1295446447&sr=1-2

Comment: You meant no problems, not now problems. Right?

Comment: Yep just can't edit it after 5 minutes..

Comment: Anytime @ picxelplay I'm glad I could help out.